# How to set the classpath for Symfony Autoloader?

Tags: symfony-1.4

I renamed my working trunk to trunk-alldone, checked out a fresh copy of trunk, ran some symfony commands (like unit tests) on trunk, then deleted trunk and renamed trunk-alldone back to trunk.

Now when I try to run any symfony commands, I get:

```
   sym cc
   PHP Warning:  require(/home/kiwi/checkouts/trunk-alldone/kiwi-    web/plugins/kcEmailPlugin/l                                                                                                                                                                     pleAutoload.class.php on line 123
    PHP Stack trace:
    PHP   1. {main}() /home/kiwi/checkouts/trunk/kiwi-web/symfony:0
    PHP   2. include() /home/kiwi/checkouts/trunk/kiwi-web/symfony:37
    PHP   3. sfCommandApplication->__construct() /home/kiwi/checkouts/trunk/kiwi-web/lib/vend
    PHP   4. sfSymfonyCommandApplication->configure() /home/kiwi/checkouts/trunk/kiwi-web/lib
    PHP   5. sfSymfonyCommandApplication->loadTasks() /home/kiwi/checkouts/trunk/kiwi-web/lib
    PHP   6. class_exists() /home/kiwi/checkouts/trunk/kiwi-web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/comman
    PHP   7. sfSimpleAutoload->autoload() /home/kiwi/checkouts/trunk/kiwi-web/lib/vendor/symf
```

It's still looking for things in trunk-alldone!

How do I reset this to get it to look in the right place again?

Comment: Ok, I've fixed my problem by manually clearing the cache (delete everything in the /cache dir).  The cached must have gotten messed up when I was switching folders.

Comment: Instead of posting a comment, post an answer and accept it.